# Angular - Change component button on different pages

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed a component in which I implemented a toolbar. There are several buttons in this toolbar, is there a way to change these buttons when I call this component on another page?

**Component name**

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
```

**Component.html**

```
   <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/upload']">
          <a class="Mais">
            <img src="assets/mais.svg" />
          </a>
          Upload Files
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

For example, can I hide the upload files button and show another button when this component is on another page, for example on the / home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **simplest way** to do this is by using **ngIf** in your app-toolbar template:

*toolbar.component.ts*

```
@Input() showUploadBtn: boolean = false;
@Input() showOtherBtn: boolean = false;
```

*toolbar.component.html*

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li *ngIf="showUploadBtn" class="nav-item btn-upload" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/upload']">
      <a class="Mais">
        <img src="assets/mais.svg" />
      </a>
      Upload Files
    </li>

    <li *ngIf="showOtherBtn">
      <button>Hi</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

*component1.component.html*

```
<app-toolbar [showUploadBtn]="true"></app-toolbar>
```

*component2.component.html*

```
<app-toolbar [showOtherBtn]="true"></app-toolbar>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you !! Best regards